# TestCafe: Tests don't pass with headless mode

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment, functional-testing, testcafe

I'm building a React app and write my functional tests using TestCafe. Here is my test script:

```
"functional-tests": "testcafe chrome src/functional-tests/ --app 'yarn start'",
```

These tests pass. But if I try to run them in headless mode:

```
"functional-tests": "testcafe 'chrome:headless' src/functional-tests/ --app 'yarn start'",
```

They fail with the following error.

```
1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified
      selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.
```

If I run `yarn start` manually in a seperate terminal (not using the `--app` flag) the headless tests pass.

How can I get the headless tests to pass using the `--app` flag? I need to run the functional tests in a CI/CD script which is why I need one command to start the server and run the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by adding [a delay to launch the app](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--app-init-delay-ms).

```
"functional-tests": "testcafe 'chrome:headless' src/functional-tests/ --app 'yarn start' --app-init-delay 4000",
```

Comment: I also recommend using the `screenshots-on-fails` option in this case.
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-s---screenshots-on-fails